# VSCODE running conda activate script upon opening cmd terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, conda

Whenever I open a new *cmd* or *powershell* instegrated terminal the terminal runs the following:

```
D:\..\..\Programming> D:/miniconda3/Scripts/activate
(base) D:\Archive\Bachelor\Programming>conda activate optim
```

with output:

```
(optim) D:\Archive\Bachelor\Programming>
```

I have been searching for the setting to do this for days and can not turn it of.
There seem to be no setting specifing this behavior nor I ever added a configuration to do so.
Can somebody explain where this is coming from?

**User Settings**

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro",
    "[perl]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "cfgweb.vscode-perl"
    },
    "window.restoreWindows": "none",
    "C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "grunt.autoDetect": "off",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "cmd": {
            "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "args": []
        }
    },
}
```

**.vscode\settings.json**

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./Bachelor_Thesis_HOTRG"
    ]
}
```

**.code-workspace**

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "../writing"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: You may not want to turn it off, as you have configured your editor to run it whenever you open a terminal (from within that editor). However as you have not configured it directly, this may ship with a plugin you have activated. Have you tried disabling one plugin after the other (perhaps something Python related by the name miniconda) and checked after each deactivation which plugin added it? If not please do so. If, please share what plugin caused that for you. Also double check if you have not occasionally made that setting yourself and you just don't remember any longer.

Comment: maybe is worth noting that no oder workspace is doing the same

Comment: What do you mean by that, that if you just open cmd prompt from within windows this also happens?

Comment: no what I mean is that i happens solely when opening a terminal in the specific workspace whose configuration I put in the question. cmd just opens normaly in external terminal and any other integrated terminal ecept for the one in this particular workspace

Comment: Aren't the plugins enabled per workspace in vscode? And just in case you may want to say that it must be in the shared configuration: There are inheritance settings, for example with the environment and the shells that is *not* within workspace configuration files but is effectively only in certain workspaces. I find it often most straight forward in trouble shooting to disable the plugins one after the other to learn about that relationship first. It is easy to activate them again later on, this is only a technique to get (intermediate) results fast.

Comment: Perhaps its not clear what I meant by that: This is for locating the editors configuration entry (or override it your workspace) so that you can control whether that init script is loaded or not. Knowing which plugin offers the functionality eases to find the name of the setting.

Comment: seems to be the python extension: Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: IntelliSense (Pylance), Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Jupyter Notebooks, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, and more.
Version: 2022.20.2
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: This is about the _python environment_, there are multiple in VSCode, find the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments - My guess is you're using miniconda, double check yourself and then make the configuration according to your wishes.

Comment: It's nice you offer that, however I think it would be better you write that summary as an answer as I don't know which configuration setting you were concerned about in the end and all of my comments (or lets say most) were for your orientation and I did very little in the end. So your write-up will be much more helpful for your future self and other visitors here on site. Writing it up will also help you to better reflect your needs, so you have an additional bonus. I'm totally fine with that.